# how to get the selected value from a drop down list and transfer it to a viewbag

Tags: asp.net, razor, foreach, viewbag

**View**

```
...Some Codes...
<select class="form-control" style = "width:400px"> 
    <option selected> select issue type </option>
    @foreach( var item in  Model._issueList)
    {
        <option>@item.issueName</option>
    }
</select>
...Some Codes...
```

**Output of my dropdown**

dropDown: *issue_one, issue_two, issue_three*

Now I want to choose my **issue_three** in my drop down and save it in a **Viewbag.select**, want should be the proper code so that I can transfer the *issue_three* to my *Viewbag.select*

**TEST**

```
...foreach code...
Viewbag.select = ????
```

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what you are asking. Code to go where?  Why are not using the Html.DropdownList helper?

Comment: @Paddy, because I'm still trying to learn how to use Html.DropdownList, I'm still learning ASP.net sorry.

Comment: My drop down list is already working, example, in my drop down list there's three option **issue_one, issue_two, issue_three**. then if I choose *issue_three* in my drop down list I want it to be transfer in the **Viewbag.select** so that I can use it in my *href ="Home/Variable?value=@Viewbag.select"*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding where you want this 'transfer' to occur - in the controller?

Comment: In my view, I want to use the selected option from my drop down list. use it as a *@Viewbag.select*

Comment: How about this, if I'm the user I chose the *issue_one* from the drop down list. and if I submit it, the *issue_one* will be put in the **@Viewbag.select**. So that if it will link to the other view, the **href = "Home/Controller?value=@Viewbag.select"** will be transfer to the other view.

Comment: I think you may be working in a slightly non-standard fashion.  Typically you should have a model that gets updated on post and the model is then used to set various items in your view.  Alternatively, it sounds like you almost want this to happen client side, which would be a different matter again.

Comment: If I use a Html.DropdownList helper, will it make my work easier? I already have a Model IList for all the issue names that are need to display in my drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**View**

```
<select class="form-control" style = "width:400px"> 
<option selected> Select Company Name </option>
@foreach (var item in Model._issueList)
{
    <option id="issueSelect" onclick="transferIssue('@item.issueNo')">@item.issueName</option> 
}
</select>
@Html.HiddenFor( m => m.variable,new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:400px", @id = "issue" })
...Some codes...
<button type ="submit" id='submit_button'>Submit</button>
```

**SCRIPT** *Use JQUERY*

```
function transferIssue(x){ $('#issue')val(); }

jQuery(document).on('click', '#submit_button', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var _issue = jQuery('#issue').val();
    var _url = '@Url.Action("Jobs")' + '?value='+ _issue;

window.location.href = _url;

});
```